# How can I hook Loopback rest connector executions?

Tags: rest, strongloop, connector, loopback

How can I intercept the rest-connector execution to format the response from a REST API connector?

I added the 'news' to the datasources.json file :

```
{
  "file": {
    "name": "file",
    "localStorage": "",
    "file": "memory.db.json",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "news": {
    "name": "news",
    "crud": false,
    "debug": true,
    "connector": "rest",
    "options": {
      "strictSSL": false
    }
  }
}
```

I bind this connector with my model in the mode-config.json file

```
{
  "_meta": {
     ...
  },
  "publication": {
    "dataSource": "news",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

That works. Now, how can I format the response provided by the news Rest API ?

I don't know where code the solution provided by the [loopback documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Connector+hooks)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new `boot file` in the boot repository.

In this boot script, I can access to the datasources component and to the  `News` (I don't know why but it starts with uppercasee) connector in order to add my hook script.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.dataSources.News.connector.observe('after execute', function (ctx, next) {

    var newRespone = ctx.res.body // Add your changes here.

    ctx.end(err, ctx, response);
  });
};
```

I can parse the REST API response and format it. \o/

Comment: simarly i want have some information from ctx.req (basically headers from incoming requests) and want send those headers downstream service (datasource), how can i achieve this?